# why content goes out of flex container?

Tags: angular, angular-material2, typescript2.0, angular-flex-layout

hy,
I have follow structure:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-around start" fxLayoutGap="2%" style="padding:2%;">


    <div fxFlex style="line-height:2;">

        <md-card>

                <md-card-content>

                   <div [outputext]="textt"></div>

                </md-card-content>


            </md-card>


    </div>


    <div fxFlex fxFlexFill style="margin-right:30px;">

        <md-card>

            <md-card-content>

                <div [outputext]="text"></div>

            </md-card-content>

        </md-card>

    </div>

</div>
```

Now for some reason it works (as expected) only on desktop browsers and on some older mobile devices, but the content goes out of flex containers on some new phones. Could anyone give any suggestions and explain why is that?
What I expect is one row on wide screen and one column on small one.
I use `flex-layout` for my website layout (and reaarranging too).
So now I started consider if I did right by choosing `flex-layout` for website layout.
I have read some solutions to use `md-grid-list` by changing `cols` attribute on screen change, but I get in doubt because I saw that it requires some additional code to determine the moment when screen changes as grid list doesn't do it on it own.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about **browser compatibility**. If they support **CSS Flexible Box Layout Module** they will run properly your code.

What I just said is written [here](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Browswer-Support) in the official GitHub page of the project.

Flex-layout for angular is still not stable and relatively new, a lot can still change. If you just check the [additions and deletions graph](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/graphs/code-frequency) you can see that a lot is changed just the last month. Difficult to say if it is profitable to continue with flex-Layout or just change with something more stable.